# Chrome - New Download Window Layout/UI?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome - Windows 7
Version 49.0.2623.28 beta-m (64-bit)

I just noticed this about 5 minutes ago and I hate it.  Is there a way to revert to the previous way the download window looked?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `chrome://flags` and change the value of `#enable-md-downloads` to Disabled